LinkedIn Lead - How to create test leads for products
I would like to test the webhook I created for lead subscriptions. However, when I try to resubmit the lead form, the webhook isn't triggered again.
Additionally, in the LinkedIn documentation, it's mentioned that we can generate test leads via the Campaign Manager.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/lead-sync/leadsync?view=li-lms-2024-04&tabs=http#test-leads
Is the same method also applicable to the product lead form? Are there any alternative methods to test the product lead form besides using the Campaign Manager?
Any suggestions would be appreciated.
